# Modifying name of ivy file generated by deliverLocal task

Tags: sbt

In SBT 0.13, what's the simplest way to modify the filename (filename pattern) of the ivy file that the SBT deliverLocal task generates? I'd like to remove the version number from the filename, for example `ivy.xml` instead of `ivy-0.1-SNAPSHOT.xml`. I'd also like to have it applied to other projects in my build. I don't want to modify the name of the ivy file when publishing, only when delivering to my project's target directory.

At the moment, I've found that the following works, but it's overkill, ugly and violates DRY:

```
def deliverPattern(outputPath: File): String = (outputPath / "[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]").absolutePath

def deliverConfig(outputDirectory: File, status: String = "release", logging: UpdateLogging.Value = UpdateLogging.DownloadOnly) =
  new DeliverConfiguration(deliverPattern(outputDirectory), status, None, logging)

deliverLocalConfiguration := deliverConfig(crossTarget.value, status = if (isSnapshot.value) "integration" else "release", logging = ivyLoggingLevel.value)
```

**UPDATE**

I've simplified the above to reference the values from the existing deliverLocalConfiguration. My current working solution looks like:

```
deliverLocalConfiguration := {
  val dlc = deliverLocalConfiguration.value
  new DeliverConfiguration((crossTarget.value / "[artifact].[ext]").absolutePath, dlc.status, dlc.configurations, dlc.logging)
}
```

I put this in `Common.scala` and reference it in all of my projects' sbt files.

Comment: You may want to add it to `~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt`.